Просмотр документов и файлов и переключение между папками в том же окне
Вот код пока только создал само окно дальше не понимаю как сделать что бы можно было бы просматривать в это окне папки и файлы.
from tkinter import *


def compile_report():
    # Действия при нажатии кнопки "Компиляция отчета"
    pass

def upload_files():
    # Действия при нажатии кнопки "Загрузка файлов"
    pass

def download_files():
    # Действия при нажатии кнопки "Выгрузка файлов"
    pass

def view_files():
    # Действия при нажатии кнопки "Просмотр файлов"
    pass

def exit_app():
    # Действия при нажатии кнопки "Выход"
    ws.destroy()




# Создаем шрифт, окно с иконкой и названием, пишем координаты в центр для окна
f = ('Times', 14)
ws = Tk()
ws.title('Озеро Данных')
ws.config(bg='#0B5A81')
p1 = PhotoImage(file="IkonkaOzeroDanih3.png")
ws.iconphoto(False, p1)
ws.geometry('700x500')
x_position, y_position = 680, 260
ws.geometry(f'700x500+{x_position}+{y_position}')


# Добавляем кнопки
compile_button = Button(ws, text="Компиляция отчета", command=compile_report, width=20)
upload_button = Button(ws, text="Загрузка файлов", command=upload_files, width=20)
download_button = Button(ws, text="Выгрузка файлов", command=download_files, width=20)
view_button = Button(ws, text="Просмотр файлов", command=view_files, width=20)
exit_button = Button(ws, text="Выход", command=exit_app, width=10)


#Само диалоговое окно
oknoraboti = Text(ws, width=60, height=27)




# Размещаем кнопки на окне с помощью place
compile_button.place(x= 510, y = 120)
upload_button.place(x= 510, y = 170)
download_button.place(x= 510, y = 220)
view_button.place(x= 510, y = 270)
exit_button.place(x= 600, y = 450)
oknoraboti.place(x = 10, y = 40)




# Запускаем бесконечный цикл обработки событий
ws.mainloop()


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
